# Aws Aurora serverless v2 will not scale down to .5 ACU even though 0 connections

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-serverless, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm running a v2 instance and from the documentation aws states you should only be paying for resources that you are actually using. I have an instance than is most of the time at 0 connections but it never scales down under 2 ACUs. See images below for reference.  I have the instance setup to scale between 0.5-16ACU.  But it doesn't seem to matter the load it always stays at a baseline of 2ACUs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From the serverless database capacity graph, it looks like something is putting load on the database, preventing it from scaling down...I have a similar setup, but the serverless database capacity graph is completely flat...

Comment: Hey, have you found the issue yet ? We're facing the exact same problem in production, our Aurora instance is almost always at 6-7 ACUs despite having 4-30 ACU range and no load is on the database. This is getting problematic as we pay for much more than what we're actually using...

Comment: I have similar observation, I am also getting ~7 ACU despite having range 1-16 ACU Range under negligible load, after hardcoding it 3 ACU, the CPU average utilisation is < 40%. Looking for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to turn off the AI monitoring on the DB.  Then restart the instance. This then started the db at the minimum.

Comment: When you say AI Monitoring, do you mean Performance Insights?

Comment: Yes, Performance Insights.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behaviour but as yet can't explain it.  We have three databases running, all with the same schema and with different ACU limits set. Our production and staging databases insist at near flatlines close to the max capacity allowed whilst one other behaves as we would expect and only shows an upscale when we actually send it load.

We have tried rebooting the instances but they immediately scale up and do not appear willing to scale down.

We have full support with AWS so will raise a ticket with them and should report back here if we get an explanation/solution

Comment: You have to turn off the AI monitoring.  Once you do this restart the instance and it should scale down to the minimum.

Comment: Ben.  Great to know you have a solution to this. Can to be more specific on what you mean by AI monitoring?

Comment: @gremebryce turn off performance insights. Then restart the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was coming back to this page again and again only to find no new answers have been added. Finally I decided to contact AWS support for it and the solution was very simple. AWS had some underlying patch added for it, which was supposed to be upgraded manually. Once the upgrade is made to all the instances in the cluster, the ACUs have come down. Now, I am planning to reduce the minimum ACU even lower to see if it can go further down (I had it set to 2 as minimum but my cluster was stuck at 4 ACUs).