# Aurora PostgresSQL Serverless V2 showing higher CPU during idle

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Component : Aurora PostgresSQL Serverless V2 (0.5 - 4 ACUs) - Multi AZ deployment

Post instance startup CPU utilization stabilizes at around 55% - 60% on writer node only and does not comes down. Reader node stabilizes at ~19%.

The only query running as checked with `pg_stat_activity` on database are as follows :

- RDS Replication
- Autovacuum
- WAL Process
- Checkpoint process
- Other Internal process

Number of connections to DB : 1

Database processes running in writer node : 13

Kindly advice what additional can be checked and probable cause of issue.

- Tried to kill Autovacuum process
- Checked number of process from  `pg_stat_activity`

Comment: Additional Info : Performance Insights is enabled. Most probably this can be the reason : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026823/aws-aurora-serverless-v2-will-not-scale-down-to-5-acu-even-though-0-connections

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could enable and review monitoring stats at OS level using AWS Aurora  Enhanced Monitoring, it will provide you details at process level and identify what process is using CPU resources.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_Monitoring.OS.Viewing.html

Comment: Tried enabling Enhanced Monitoring, however the total CPU % consumtion of all OS processes amounted upto 15% which did not match with CPU% showed in console.